# how to use base param in flash

Tags: flash, relative-path, swfobject, radix

I have a **flash file**(full link to flash looks like http://localhost:8888/PROJECT/swf/audio/player.swf) which loads **mp3-file**(link to mp3 I send with php through flashvars)

I've embed dynamically(with swfobject) this swf to my page. It's ok. Then I send **ajax-request** to script, which reloading div with flash. Div is empty.

Experimentally I found out that I've trouble with **relative** paths. Flash file embed with this address ./swf/audio/player.swf and mp3-address is ./media/audio/user/1/random.mp3.
Relative to the root dir those paths are correct.

But if I change mp3-address with ../../media/audio/user/1/random.mp3 everything **works** as it should!

I've searched and found that there is 'base' param in flash, which set the root dir for flash relative paths. I try use it like this: var params = {base:"http://localhost:8888/PROJECT/"}; but without result.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swf's starting location for relative paths is based on the base param. If base is not set, it will default to the position of the html page holding the .swf, wherever the swf is.

http://localhost:8888/PROJECT/media/audio/user/1/random.mp3

This should be the path to you mediea if the param is set as .../PROJECT/

Be carefull with dots in front of paths in AS2, (a single .), it will fail in AS2 sometimes. Try with or without slashes at the end of the base path or at the start of the relative path. Simple things like that can mess up the paths so that they are not readable.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Can you clarify, please, how should 'base' param look like? Is it correct? - base:"http://localhost:8888/PROJECT/"

Comment: It can look whatever you want as long as it's correct and the .swf can see it. The project I am working on right now, the server seems to have "blabla/pathDir" as the base param so that forces relative paths that start with slashes "/static/flash/etc" inside the as2 swf (funny thing is that this will sometimes cause the .swf to fail in local)... I guess you should try "http://localhost" etc but also make sure your security sandbox is correct, it might be the problem on the browser (install a debug version of flash in the browser, it will show runtime errors).